# How to select JSON with results?

Tags: android, json, listview

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "server_response": [{
        "bmw": "",
        "mercedes": "",
        "honda": "civic",
        "toyota": "corolla",
        "gmc": "",
        "chevy": ""
    }]
}
```

Here is my Android code:

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("server_response");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
//this is the problem here. How can I get JSON that has a result like Honda and Toyota?
                    {variable name} = jsonChildNode.optString("{problem is here}");
                    CarsModel carsModel new CarsModel( {variable name} {variable name} );
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The problem is in the Android code as you can see. I want it to only get the JSON that is **not empty**, for example honda and toyota.

How can replace {variable name} with in this case, honda and then replace {problem is here} with the json result that's not blank?

I also want to add the {variable names} into the `CarsModel carsModel new CarsModel( {variable name} {variable name} );`.

Comment: loop on server_response, skip any empty values...

Comment: @MarcB How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
    // Get the keys in the JSON object
    Iterator<?> keys = jsonChildNode.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        // Get the key
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String objValue = jsonChildNode.getString(key);
        // check if empty
        if (!objValue.isEmpty()) {
            CarsModel carsModel new CarsModel(objValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I put this in the for loop?

Comment: My bad, it actual has to be inside the `for-loop`.

Comment: Okay but it still says 
 
jsonMainNode.keys(); cannot resolve method "keys()"

Comment: Use the child to get the keys, `jsonChildNode.keys()`.

Comment: I've looked at your code. It is almost working. Change `if (keys.hasNext()) {` to `while (keys.hasNext()) {`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do. The data you want is a json object inside a jsonArray

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("server_response");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                variableX = jsonChildNode.getString("toyota");
                variableY = jsonChildNode.getString("honda");
                variableZ = jsonChildNode.getString("xyz");

//              CarsModel thing using var x, y, z...
            }
```

Comment: Since server response is in array, you have to loop to access all the values